# Limitation of acceptable types in generic class to types uses in interface

Tags: c#, .net, generics

It's me again.

I hope that u will help me again ( and again understand what I want to ask )

I have interface :

```
public interface i
{
    string a {get;set;}
    int b {get;set;}
    classname c {get;set;}
}
```

And i want to cereate generic class:

```
 public class someclass<T>
 {

 T _value;
 public sobeclass(T value)
 {
     _value = value;
 }
```

But i wont that T will can have only type form the i Interface

I hope that u understand me

Thank you for help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [where generic type constraint](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384067.aspx):

```
public class someclass<T>
  where T : I
{
  ...
}
```

Comment: Note that `T` can be a class implementing `I`, *or* an interface extending `I`, *or* `I` itself.

Comment: This method allow me to put in place of T instance to the interface e.g when class C : I 
I will able to place C or I in place of T but i need to place C.a

Comment: @Aht You mean you want to constrain `T` to `string`, `int`, or `classname`? You can't do that. If you have a limited set of unrelated type, you'll have to provide overloads for each of those types.

Comment: Or find what's common among those types, abstract that using the [Adapter pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/adapter-pattern.html), and constraint `T` to `IAdapter` - but I don't think your types have anything in common.

Comment: @Aht I did no fully understand your comment. Are you trying to achieve what dcastro wrote?

Comment: I try to do some class like that :
I have few class C:I in list and i want to sort this list by property e.g. string a or int b, but need to do this in one method so i try send to method an sorting parameter e.g. C.b

Comment: So you have a List<I> which you want to sort by one of I's properties. But what does it have to do with creating a generic class?

Comment: @Aht This is an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Post a new question, describe the issue you're having with sorting your data, and post your current solution and your code. But it sounds like LINQ's [`OrderBy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534966(v=vs.100).aspx) is what you need.